# Populate a dropdown menu from a MySQL database in a WordPress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress site in which I want to show to the user a list of cities to choose from and show in a Google map.

I have made a HTML dropdown menu which I want to populate with cities which are retrieved from a MySQL table named Map_of_resellers.

Problem is, the dropdown box is shown in the page but it's empty (it has no entries).

The code I use shows me if the connection to the database is successful and also if the db query is succesfull so these are not the issues.

If you wonder what the [insert_php] and [/insert_php] tags are, they are shortcodes to allow PHP in a WordPress page since it's not supported natively.
They are used by a WordPress plugin named Insert PHP which i installed for this purpose.

Here is my PHP code:

```
[insert_php]

$servername = "sql102.*******.com";
$username = "b3_*******";
$password = "********";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

mysqli_select_db('b3_**********');

$sql="SELECT City FROM Map_of_resellers";

$result=mysqli_query($sql);


if($result === FALSE)
{
die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error());  
}

[/insert_php]


<form name="Cities" method="post" >

[insert_php]

echo "<select name='City'>";


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
echo "<option value='" . $row['City'] ."'>" . 
$row['City']."</option>";
}

echo "</select>";

[/insert_php]

</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Learn how to make your own shortcodes. Totally worth it in a case like this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [source code](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/insert-php/trunk/insert_php.php) for the plugin you mentioned, it uses `eval` to parse the PHP code. New variables created inside an evaluated script won't be in scope when the evaluation has ended. So `$results` won't be accessible in your second code block.

Replacing the code like below should keep $results in scope and fix the issue:

```
[/insert_php]


<form name="Cities" method="post" >

[insert_php]
```

to

`echo '<form name="Cities" method="post" >';`